# Fails to boot, network time syncronization fails to start in recovery mode in 18.04

Tags: boot

My ubuntu 18.04 wks fails to boot, stays at kubuntu screen with 4 dots underneath. When I boot into recovery mode I get the message that: "Network time synchronization failed," then repeats without ever actually completing the boot cycle.

This happened after an update, it updated a couple of dozen packages so I am unsure which package has caused the failure. I can boot into a live cd, however, the `timedatectl` command only works on the cd. If I chroot to where I have mounted the original root filesystem and `mount -t proc proc /proc`, the `timedatectl` command no longer works.

I believe if I am able to turn off time synchronization my computer will be able to boot successfully and allow me to look into the updates to correct the original problem. Which file do I need to modify to do this manually?

Comment: Thanks David for your suggestions on wording my question.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to have been caused by an error when the linux-image file was updated.
Booting into rescue mode & setting the root directory to RW, I was unable to execute any apt commands.
It had an error regarding the hosts file.
I updated the hosts file to include the hostname.
I was then able to execute apt commands.
Once apt install --reinstall linux-image had completed & rebooted the workstation.
I was able to boot the workstation up as per normal.
Thank you for taking the time to read my post & hopefully this may help someone else.